# Angular .Net DLL Possible Integration

Tags: .net, angular

Are there any frameworks enabling Angular to call a .net dll without making a service call.  We have created a dll for a DB to enable it to encrypt/decrypt SSN without making a web service call.  If the UI can call it too, that would eliminate the need to send unencrypted SSN's to the App server over the network to have the SSN encrypted.  The idea would be all 3 tiers could use the same dll.

Comment: Why not use an SSL certificate to encrypt the network channel? That is the standard accepted approach to encrypted communication from client (browser) to server.

Comment: To answer your question: No, you can't call into a dll (.net or native) from javascript (as angular is javascript framework built with Typescript, a superset of javascript, it also applies here). Javascript executes in a sandbox, if you really did want to pursue this route you would need to elevate permissions and find some library that could make the native call. Personally I would strongly discourage it.

Comment: Thank you @Igor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [Blazor](http://learn-blazor.com/architecture/interop/) a try, because you can call a C# method from javascript:

From the link:

```
// Define a very simple JavaScript function that just prints
// the input parameter to the browser's console
window.say = async (data) => {
   // Demonstrate how to call a C# method from JavaScript
   console.log(await DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('RestApi.Client', 'Concat',
              'Recieved call ', 'from C#. ', 'Here is the received parameter:'));

   console.dir(data);

  // Your function currently has to return something. For demo
  // purposes, we just return `true`.
  return true;
};
```

And the C# method:

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RestApi.Client.Pages
{
   public static class StringUtil
   {
       [JSInvokable]
       public static Task<string> Concat(string str1, string str2, string str3)
       {
           return Task.FromResult(string.Concat(str1, str2, str3));
       }
   }
 }
```

Now, keep in mind, that using Blazor may have a small learning curve and probably won't solve the security issue. Please read the documentation before using it for this particular purpose.